How to ensure background image covers entire page in PDF?
I am using the html2pdf.js library in my Node.js application to generate a multi-page PDF from HTML content. The content is generated dynamically and displayed in a #slideContainer div. I want to set a background image that covers the entire page (including areas without HTML content) for each page of the PDF.
Current Setup


document.getElementById("generatePdfButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  // Temporarily show all slides
  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.add("active");
  });

  const pdfContent = document.getElementById("slideContainer");
  const options = {
    margin: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    filename: "XXXXX",
    image: {
      type: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.98
    },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 2,
      useCORS: true
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: "in",
      format: "a4",
      orientation: "landscape"
    },
    pagebreak: {
      mode: ["avoid-all", "css", "legacy"]
    },
  };

  html2pdf()
    .set(options)
    .from(pdfContent)
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      // Revert slides back to their original state
      showSlide(currentSlide);
    });
});
#slideContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Center slides vertically */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* Ensure the container takes at least the full height of the viewport */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Allow scrolling if content overflows */
}

.slide {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* Center content horizontally */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Center content vertically */
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: url("/images/background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 20px 0;
  /* Add some space between slides */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* Avoid page breaks inside slides */
}
<div id="slideContainer">
  <div class="slide">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Content here...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="generatePdfButton">Generate PDF</button>



Issue:
The background image does not cover the entire page in the PDF. It only appears where the HTML content exists, leaving blank spaces on the rest of the page.
Desired Outcome:
I want the background image to span the entire page (including areas without HTML content) for every page of the PDF.

Question:
How can I ensure that the background image covers the full dimensions of each page in the generated PDF using html2pdf? Is there a workaround for html2pdf's limitations, or am I missing something in my implementation?
Any guidance or examples would be appreciated!

Does this help: How to get rid of the left and top margins in css

It is a PHP library designed to work in a server-side PHP environment. my current implementation uses JavaScript and the html2pdf library, which runs in the browser.

FYI: As seen in your snippet, margin: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], - Did you change the margins here already to 0?

Yes I used margin 0. But it does not work.
